# Forwarding request to jsp and showing loading div

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, httprequest

I have 2 jsp pages and a servlet. Let's say `first.jsp`, `Process.java` and `second.jsp.` What can I do if I want that as soon as I submit first.jsp and start processing my logic on the servlet, I redirect to second.jsp and display a loading sign until Process is ready? I am aware that that I can use the following code so that I display a loading sign on first.jsp but how can I forward the request to second.jsp and display the loading sign there?

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'process',
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    beforeSend:function()
    {
        // append loading div
    },
    success:function(data)
    {
        // successful request        
    },
    error:function()
    {
        // failed request
    }
});
```

Comment: so why use ajax for it?

Comment: I am just saying a way that I could do for having a loading div on first.jsp while logic in Process is running. That way I can have the ajax request and append the div on the beforeSend. My question is how this can be done to display loading image on second.jsp. I didn't say it has to be ajax

Comment: Okay! but what if ajax request done before landing on second.jsp

Comment: I don't understand your question. If I have the ajax request on first.jsp and it is done before landing on second.jsp, then obviously it would be like I have it now, loading sign on first.jsp and redirect after. Is this the only way that could be done?

Comment: See you can **add a div with css class `.loader` with a loading gif img on second jsp**, when you land on second jsp then you can remove that div with js or **you can replace the html content**.

Comment: What are you asking? Is there redirection taking place in the servlet the Ajax request was sent to? Or you want to redirect the main page after the Ajax returns?

Comment: @developerwjk I want to send a request to the servlet from a jsp page and while the logic in the servlet is processing, the program displays a loading page on another jsp page instead on the first one from which the request was sent

Comment: @Bernice, I don't get what you mean by another jsp page. Just use Javascript to set a div to say "Loading...", send the Ajax request, and then put the response in the div when the Ajax returns.

Comment: @developerwjk I'm saying that I want the loading div to appear on the page I am going to show results on and not on the page from where I am submitting the request. I dont know if that is possible.

Comment: Then you submit from page 1 to page 2, and then have the ajax request fire in page 2 in the onLoad method.

Comment: true, so simple and yet it didn't come to my mind! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @developerwjk if I have a form and I am submitting it to second.jsp, is there a better way to get all values from second.jsp than getParameter() for each parameter involved? I have quite a lot of parameters so I'm hoping there is a way in which I can forward the whole form instead to the servlet?

Comment: I don't know if I was clear.. I'm asking if there is a way to forward the request to the second.jsp and send the request via ajax to the servlet from there